# How to disable a sidebar in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme with two sidebars. I want to disable one for them for a specific page but the code I found regarding disabling sidebar by applying check on function:

```
<?php get_sidebar() ?>
```

It will disable both of them. How can I  disable one of them only. with the other sidebar working.

Please help!!!!

Comment: I am using Contentville theme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply for example

```
<?php if (!is_page('about-me')) get_sidebar(); ?>
```

This will disable sidebar on about me page. If you put this on page.php (if have any) otherwise put this on index.php. Here 'about-me' is page slug but you can also use page id like is_page(5) and as well as page title too. To check multiple page using slug, id and title you can use an array like

```
is_page(array(42,'about-me','Contact'));
```

For more about is_page() function see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Or using filter in functions.php, simply put this in functions.php

```
function disable_footer_widgets( $sidebars_widgets )
{
    if (is_single())
    {
        $sidebars_widgets['footer'] = false;
    }   
    return $sidebars_widgets;
}
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'disable_footer_widgets' );
```

This is just an example, you have to change widget name.

Comment: You don't get my question. I want to disable only one widget and display the other. But your code is for disabling all the widgets i have already done that...